# Installation guide for ADT bundle for windows

Tags: android, eclipse

Recently, there's a new android SDK- "ADT bundle for windows" which includes everything but jdk. Thats why when I run eclipse, it says-" JRE / JDK must be available to run eclipse, No JRE/JDK found in ...[my unzipped folder location]" I tried adding the following (at the begining) line in eclipse.ini, but to NO avail.

> --vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06

What should I do to run eclipse bundle.

Comment: I first downloaded the "ADT bundle for windows" When it said it JDE or JRE must be available for the ADT to start, then I downloaded the JDE for the JAVA website. After downloading the JDE I was able to open the ADT perfectly well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be: -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin\javaw.exe"

PS: It is better for JDK home not having spaces, like in 'Program Files' !!

Refer this [Link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

Comment: I tried -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin\javaw.exe"  but it also didnt work. How come the developer site didnt mention that.

Comment: I sorted it out, I included the - "" in the path. After I deleted the parentheses, its working well. Thanx by the way.